# How can I update extreme columns within range fast?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 40 tables that look like following, and each table contains 30 million records.

Table `RawData` : PK(`CaregoryID`, `Time`)

```
CategoryID  Time                        IsSampled  Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
1           2012-07-01 00:00:00.000     0 -> 1     65.36347
1           2012-07-01 00:00:11.000     0          80.16729
1           2012-07-01 00:00:14.000     0          29.19716
1           2012-07-01 00:00:25.000     0 -> 1      7.05847
1           2012-07-01 00:00:36.000     0 -> 1     98.08257
1           2012-07-01 00:00:57.000     0          75.35524
1           2012-07-01 00:00:59.000     0          35.35524
```

As of now, the `IsSampled` column is 0 for all records. 
I need to update the records, so that for each CategoryID and for each minute range, the records with Max(Value), Min(Value), and the first record should have 1 for `IsSampled`.

Following is the procedural query I've created, but it takes too long to run. (approx. 2h 30m for each table)

```
DECLARE @startRange datetime 
DECLARE @endRange datetime 
DECLARE @endTime datetime 
SET @startRange = '2012-07-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @endTime = '2012-08-01 00:00:00.000'

WHILE (@startRange < @endTime)
BEGIN
    SET @endRange = DATEADD(MI, 1, @startRange)

    UPDATE r1
    SET IsSampled = 1
    FROM RawData AS r1
    JOIN 
    (
      SELECT r2.CategoryID, 
             MAX(Value) as MaxValue, 
             MIN(Value) as MinValue, 
             MIN([Time]) AS FirstTime
      FROM RawData AS r2
      WHERE @startRange <= [Time] AND [Time] < @endRange
      GROUP BY CategoryID
    ) as samples
    ON r1.CategoryID = samples.CategoryID
       AND (r1.Value = samples.MaxValue 
            OR r1.Value = samples.MinValue 
            OR r1.[Time] = samples.FirstTime)
       AND @startRange <= r1.[Time] AND r1.[Time] < @endRange

    SET @startRange = DATEADD(MI, 1, @startRange)   
END
```

Is there a way to update these tables faster(presumably in non-procedural way)? Thanks!

Comment: what is the number of affected rows on such update?

Comment: on average, 1.5 million records should be updated for each table.(
typically there is one record for every second, so (30 mil / 60) * 3 = 1.5 mil

Comment: Would you consider changing PK to (Time, CategoryID)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with indices, but my colleague told me that it is better to set PK as (CategoryID, Time), because the records are typically searched by CategoryID first, then Time for this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the performance of this will be like, but it's a more set-based approach than your current one:

```
declare @T table (CategoryID int not null,Time datetime2 not null,IsSampled bit not null,Value decimal(10,5) not null)
insert into @T (CategoryID,Time,IsSampled,Value) values
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:00.000',0,65.36347),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:11.000',0,80.16729),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:14.000',0,29.19716),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:25.000',0,7.05847),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:36.000',0,98.08257),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:57.000',0,75.35524),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:59.000',0,35.35524)

;with BinnedValues as (
    select CategoryID,Time,IsSampled,Value,DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,Time),0) as TimeBin
    from @T
), MinMax as (
    select CategoryID,Time,IsSampled,Value,TimeBin,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID, TimeBin ORDER BY Value) as MinPos,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID, TimeBin ORDER BY Value desc) as MaxPos,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID, TimeBin ORDER BY Time) as Earliest
    from
        BinnedValues
)
update MinMax set IsSampled = 1 where MinPos=1 or MaxPos=1 or Earliest=1

select * from @T
```

Result:

```
CategoryID  Time                   IsSampled Value
----------- ---------------------- --------- ---------------------------------------
1           2012-07-01 00:00:00.00 1         65.36347
1           2012-07-01 00:00:11.00 0         80.16729
1           2012-07-01 00:00:14.00 0         29.19716
1           2012-07-01 00:00:25.00 1         7.05847
1           2012-07-01 00:00:36.00 1         98.08257
1           2012-07-01 00:00:57.00 0         75.35524
1           2012-07-01 00:00:59.00 0         35.35524
```

It could possibly be sped up if the `TimeBin` column could be added as a computed column to the table and added to appropriate indexes.

It should also be noted that this will mark a *maximum* of 3 rows as sampled - if the earliest is also the min or max value, it will only be marked once (obviously), but the next nearest min or max value will not be. Also, if multiple rows have the same `Value`, and that is the min or max value, one of the rows will be selected arbitrarily.

Comment: Wow. when ran agains a table with 1 mil. records, this query runs in 7 seconds where the original query takes 57 seconds. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite update in the loop to something like:

```
   UPDATE r1
   SET   IsSampled = 1
   FROM  RawData r1
   WHERE r1.Time >= @startRange and Time < @endRange

   AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        select *
        from    RawData r2
        where   r2.CategoryID = r1.CategoryID
        and     r2.Time >= @startRange and r2.Time < @endRange 
        and     (r2.Time < r1.Time or r2.Value < r1.Value or r2.Value > r1.Value)
    )
```

To get actual performance  improvement you need an index on Time column.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this query.

```
declare @T table (CategoryID int not null,Time datetime2 not null,IsSampled bit not null,Value decimal(10,5) not null)
insert into @T (CategoryID,Time,IsSampled,Value) values
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:00.000',0,65.36347),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:11.000',0,80.16729),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:14.000',0,29.19716),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:25.000',0,7.05847),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:36.000',0,98.08257),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:57.000',0,75.35524),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:59.000',0,35.35524)


;WITH CTE as (SELECT CategoryID,CAST([Time] as Time) as time,IsSampled,Value FROM @T)

,CTE2 as (SELECT CategoryID,Max(time) mx,MIN(time) mn,'00:00:00.0000000' as start FROM CTE where time <> '00:00:00.0000000' Group by CategoryID)

update @T SET IsSampled=1
FROM CTE2 c inner join @T t on c.CategoryID = t.CategoryID and (CAST(t.[Time] as Time)=c.mx or CAST(t.[Time] as Time)=c.mn or CAST(t.[Time] as Time)=c.start)

select * from @T
```

Comment: The min and max the OP is searching for are the min and max values within that time range - not the min and max times.

Comment: In that case I guess for the given sample table,we should have IsSampled = 1 for 59sex max,11 sec min and 00 sec rite?

Comment: No, the maximum value (98.08257) occurs at 36 seconds. The minimum (7.05847) occurs at 25 seconds. In the table at the top of the OP's question, they show which rows they want to transition from 0 to 1 by showing ` -> 1`

Comment: Ohh sorry I was thinking of max and min Time.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Here is the latest updated query.
Check the query for performance:

```
declare @T table (CategoryID int not null,Time datetime2 not null,IsSampled bit not null,Value decimal(10,5) not null)
insert into @T (CategoryID,Time,IsSampled,Value) values
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:00.000',0,65.36347),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:11.000',0,80.16729),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:14.000',0,29.19716),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:25.000',0,7.05847),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:36.000',0,98.08257),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:57.000',0,75.35524),
(1,'2012-07-01T00:00:59.000',0,35.35524)


;WITH CTE as (SELECT CategoryID,Time,CAST([Time] as Time) as timepart,IsSampled,Value FROM @T)
--SELECT * FROM CTE

,CTE2 as (SELECT CategoryID,Max(value) mx,MIN(value) mn FROM CTE 
where timepart <> '00:00:00.0000000' and Time <=DATEADD(MM,1,Time)
 Group by CategoryID)

,CTE3 as (SELECT CategoryID,Max(value) mx,MIN(value) mn FROM CTE 
where timepart = '00:00:00.0000000' and Time <=DATEADD(MM,1,Time)
 Group by CategoryID)

update @T SET IsSampled=1
FROM @T t left join CTE2 c1
on (t.CategoryID = c1.CategoryID  and (t.Value = c1.mn or t.Value =c1.mx))
left join CTE3 c3 on(t.CategoryID = c3.CategoryID and t.Value = c3.mx)
where (c1.CategoryID is not null or c3.CategoryID is not null)


select * from @T
```

Comment: Hello Anand, thanks for your answer. however, the query result differs from what I intended. the IsSampled column should be marked for every minute range, but this query marks the column for the whole range.